# Calculating holes on a Tetris grid quickly

Tags: java, performance, bitwise, tetris

I have created a Tetris AI which can play Tetris on its own given a set of rules. It places the next piece in every possible way on the board, and calculates which position that gives the fewest "holes" on the playfield.

The playfield is represented by an `int[]` array, where every bit represents a position in a row, and every `int` represents a row.

A playfield can look like this:

```
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)0111111111
(0000000000000000000000)0111111111
(0000000000000000000000)0111001111
(0000000000000000000000)0111100111
```

the zeroes in parentheses are not part of the playfield, and are not used. 1 represents an empty square, 0 represents a filled one. So the example above would be a long piece on the left, and a squiggly piece in the middle.

However, to determine if this playfield is "desirable", I calculate the number of holes on the grid. A hole is defined as follows:

- An empty square under the topmost filled square in a column.
- An empty square in a column next to a column where we have found a filled square, given that the empty square in question is under the topmost filled square in the other column.

I guess it's hard to explain, but I've marked all "holes" here:

```
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)1111111111
(0000000000000000000000)0X11111111
(0000000000000000000000)0X11111111
(0000000000000000000000)0X1X00X111
(0000000000000000000000)0X11D00X11
```

Every hole is marked with an "X", except for one in the bottom row, since that one is counted twice, because it is under a filled square, and next to a square that is  under a filled square.

Right now this is the optimal solution that I've found. It is a combination of JS1's and Brythan's solutions:

```
private static int EMPTY_ROW = (1<<xsize)-1;

public int calcHolesConverted(int[] grid) {
    //int gridMask      = (1 << xsize) - 1;
    int underMask     = 0;
    int lneighborMask = 0;
    int rneighborMask = 0;
    int foundHoles    = 0;
    int minY = 0;

    while ( minY < ysize && grid[minY] == EMPTY_ROW ) {
        minY++;
    }

    for (int y = minY; y < ysize; y++) {
        int line   = grid[y];
        int filled = ~line & EMPTY_ROW;

        underMask     |= filled;
        lneighborMask |= (filled << 1);
        rneighborMask |= (filled >> 1);

        foundHoles += setOnes[underMask & line];
        foundHoles += setOnes[lneighborMask & line];
        foundHoles += setOnes[rneighborMask & line];
    }
    return foundHoles;
}
```

This results in over 10000 Tetris pieces per second, compared to the 4800 that I could accomplish before I asked the question.

Comment: The number of set bits in a int can be calculated with [Integer.bitCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int))

Can I ask why performance is an issue, and how you know it is this method?

Comment: Performance is an issue because at this point I want to optimize the program as much as possible. I can drop 4500 Tetris pieces per second as of now, and I having a bottleneck bothers me. I precalculate the bitCount values, since I only need 1024 values. Looping through every grid position, and checking every bit three times seems very time consuming, compared to my other methods. This method takes up over 50% of execution time, with my second heaviest method (which has been optimized a lot more) takes up 40%.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but @maxb, I haven't found anything on Google about your setOnes array, can you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: The setOnes array is precalculated, in order to quickly find the number of set bits in an integer. For example, setOnes[14] = 3, since 14 = 1110b. I ended up using the solution shown above, since other bottlenecks were more dominant.

Comment: @maxb Another question, how did you get that definition of holes? Especially the second "rule". Has this something to do with column/row transitions? Also, did you publish your final version somewhere?

Comment: @Sven The second rule was made up by me. I was trying a lot of different functions for evaluating game boards, and that rule seemed to work well. The second rule helps to even out the game board by minimizing the height difference of adjacent columns. The paper i wrote on this can be found here: http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:815662/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this faster by doing the whole row at once instead of one bit at a time.  All you need to do is to keep a mask of bits that correspond to your `firstFound` booleans.  To match the OP's counting scheme (which can triply count a hole), I keep three masks: an `underMask`, an `lNeighborMask`, and an `rNeighborMask`.  `underMask` is used to count holes underneath the topmost filled square in a column.  `lNeighborMask` is used to count holes to the left of the column.  `rNeighborMask` is used to count holes to the right of the column.  (I edited my original answer to account for the triple counting).

## The Code

```java
public int calcHolesConverted(int[] grid)
{
    int gridMask      = (1 << xsize) - 1;
    int underMask     = 0;
    int lNeighborMask = 0;
    int rNeighborMask = 0;
    int foundHoles    = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < ysize; y++) {
        int line   = grid[y];
        int filled = ~line & gridMask;

        underMask     |= filled;
        lNeighborMask |= (filled << 1);
        rNeighborMask |= (filled >> 1);

        foundHoles += setOnes1024[underMask & line] +
                      setOnes1024[lNeighborMask & line] +
                      setOnes1024[rNeighborMask & line];
    }
    return foundHoles;
}
```

In this code, `setOnes1024` is an array of size 1024 which contains the number of 1 bits in the corresponding index.  It is analagous to your `setOnes` array.  Also, this code assumes that the bits to the left of the leftmost column will all be 0.  If they are not, then you will need to adjust `lneighborMask` to not contain bits outside the valid columns.

## The Timing Test

I ran this timing test by converting both functions to C and running them on the same randomized grid (20000000 iterations each function).

```
OP's function    : 8.2 seconds
Modified function: 1.4 seconds
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `neighborMask = ((filled << 1) | (filled >> 1)) | underMask;` (no `|=`) and then you can get rid of the first `foundHoles +=` statement.  You seem to be counting some holes twice plus you count holes under places that used to be adjacents but may no longer be.

Comment: @Brythan If you trace through the OP's code, it does exactly what mine does.  Once it finds the first filled square in a column, it starts counting all squares in the three columns (left, center, right) of the current column.  The OP's code in fact can triple count some holes, which I have edited my code to do as well.

Comment: Wow, this is really fast. My program went from placing 5200 Tetris pieces per second to 9200 pieces per second. This was exactly what I was thinking (not your actual solution, but being able to remove a `for`-loop). Great job! Note: Combining your solution with Brythans solution by adding his first `while`-loop with `minY` set to 0 to begin with actually makes it about 10% faster

Comment: And to clarify: the reason why I count some holes twice or thrice is because those holes are "worse", and I want to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 6):

> - An empty square under the topmost filled square in a column.
> - An empty square in a column next to a column where we have found a filled square, given that the empty square in question is under the topmost filled square in the other column.

Note that both of these are limited to squares at or below the top row with a filled square.  So you don't have to fully check every row.

Assuming rows are numbered from top to bottom rather than bottom to top:

```
final private static int EMPTY_ROW = 0x3FF;

public int calcHolesConverted(int[] grid, int minY) {
    int foundHoles = 0;

    while ( grid[minY] == EMPTY_ROW && minY < ysize ) {
        minY++;
    }

    int x = xsize-1;
    while ( x >= 0 ) {
        int bitMask = 1 << x;
        for ( int y = minY; y < ysize; y++ ) {
            if (grid[y] & bitMask == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        x--;

        for ( ; y < ysize; y++ ) {
            foundHoles += setOnes[(grid[y] >> x) & 7];
        }
    }

    return foundHoles;
}
```

Note that you can determine the maximum height for any piece by a simple lookup.  Then you just need to know the current depth of the board and subtract the piece height from that.  This happens outside the function and you pass this value into the function as `minY`.  This saves the first few iterations of checking the board.  I'd write this code, but there is insufficient context in the question.

The function itself then checks the current board arrangement and eliminates the empty rows at the top by comparing the value of an empty row with the current row.  It updates `minY` until a non-empty row is found.  I include a check of `minY < ysize`, but you can skip this if there's always at least one non-empty row in `grid`.

I removed the `firstFound` boolean in favor of two loops.  This saves checking for the `firstFound` condition once it has been found.  And it saves checking `firstFound` at all in the second loop.

I moved the `x--` so as to save the unnecessary `x-1`.  Note that the compiler may or may not have optimized that out.  Once I did that, it seemed unnecessary to continue using a `for` loop, so I switched to the `while`.  That's entirely stylistic though.

Instead of shifting `grid[y]` on every iteration, I shift `1` once before starting.  There may be a way to do this with `setOnes` as well, but it looks more complicated.  It might use more memory but save time.  You don't include the definition of `setOnes`, so I won't try modifying the code for this purpose.

Comment: I implemented this, and it is really fast. In the first while, should it be `grid[minY]` instead of `grid[y]`? Also when adding the lines, you are forgetting about the special case where x = 0. Then we only want to look at the current column and the column to the right. I made it work using `foundHoles += setOnes[grid[y]<<1 & 7<<x];` which seems to have about the same performance, and giving a better result. Thank you a lot for your answer, it really helped me!